Keyboard behaves weird after last update
After last upgrade my Keyboard started to work extremly weird.
I have a logitech ERGO K660.
For example, when clicking SUPER key and ALT, mouse scrolling stops in window and it scrolls the workspaces. When clicking ESCAPE it switches the active window. When clicking SHIFT the next key is capital. And several different things.
One situation (I do not know how I made it) mey keyboard only wrote special characters.
There was an update in the morning, and I had to restart my laptop mid-day. After the restart the problems began.
What could cause this problems? Might it be the update?
Output from uname -a:
Linux XXX 6.5.0-35-generic #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue May  7 09:00:52 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Output from lsb_release -a:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

I install updates as far as Ubuntu Desktop propose to do it.

We haven't been told what Ubuntu product/release you're using, so we can't yet explore (or know) what updates are possible for your unstated Ubuntu product/release, let alone how often you apply fixes (eg. do you check daily? weekly? or multiple times in a day, let alone which mirror you use (which can impact when your system sees them as available)).  We're limited to details you provide, which currently is rather limited as we don't know what you're actually running yet.  If your keyboard is wireless, have you checked batteries? or checked for radio interference around your machine etc?

I suggest applying security fixes, or exploring why you haven't applied all fixes (package issues maybe, or bad configuration made by user with sudo rights) as your details highlight you're behind on applying fixes for some time... ie. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/02/22/ubuntu-22-04-4-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date of 22.04.4, however installed systems upgraded before that ISO release date.

Thanks for your hint @guiverc, but when running apt update and apt list --upgrabale it says, there is nothing to update.

FYI:  Your details mention you've been applying security fixes, but also very clearly factually highlight you haven't... so something is wrong with your question.  If you're using Ubuntu, an updated 22.04 system will report (and has awhile now) as 22.04.4; so apply all upgrades..  If you're using however a Ubuntu based system, then you're off-topic here, and the based on is your issue (and would explain 22.04.3), eg. Linux Mint is based on Ubuntu but can put holds* on security fixes as they interfere with runtime adjustments etc. they use for upstream Ubuntu packages

In regards your last comment, I'd either check your sources & ensure nothing is missing (which would explain why upgraded packages wouldn't be detected & thus don't show) & then sudo apt update & check no missing lines/warnings/errors etc.. (ie. same check as checking sources; just another way - I prefer checking my sources; but both will work)   Your question matches a Ubuntu based system [in my opinion] more than an actual Ubuntu system for example; otherwise if Ubuntu you have corrupted sources which would explain contradictions in question

Thanks @guiverc for your comments. My system is update to date now and I found the problem with my keyboard: Accessibility -> Turn on sticky keys

Write your own answer then; you can gain some REP (when you accept it).

Finally I found out, that the problem results in the setting "Turn on sticky keys" (Settings -> Accessibility).
Somehow (not sure how) this was activated and my keyboard behaved different:
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/a11y-stickykeys.html.en
